# Flask app structure is giving me module headaches

Tags: python, import, flask

I'm a newcomer to Python and Flask so I may be completely off with my app's organization. Here's what the directory structure looks like:

```
  + venv
    + bin
    + include
    + lib
    + myapp
      - __init__.py
      + config
        - __init__.py
        - development.py
        - production.py
      + templates
        - layout.html
        (more html files here and directories)
      + db
        - development.db
        - production.db
      + static
        (all my css/js/etc)
      + views
        - __init__.py
        - main.py
      + models
        - __init__.py
        - game.py
```

Everything has worked so far, until I started working on models. I'm trying to `import myapp.models.game` and for some reason it doesn't work. Instead it complains saying the `myapp` module doesn't exist.

Why is this happening and what am I missing? Should I be organizing files in a different way?

Comment: what have you done to cause the path to `myapp` to be on your python path?  Do you have a `setup.py`?

Comment: Nope, I have my bootstrapping code (the code that starts the Flask app and the database) in the top most `__init__.py`

Comment: What file does that error come from? Are you successfully importing myapp in other parts of your code?

Comment: @DG1: I'm not - but I feel like I should. Instead of `from config import development` it seems like it would be nicer to `from myapp.config import development`. I get the error when trying to get SQLAlchemy to write my schema to the database. In my virtualenv, I go into a python shell and try importing `myapp` to get the `db` object I create in `__init__.py`. That fails.

Comment: What directory are you in when you open the shell?

Comment: @DG1: in the `myapp` directory. I just tried it from the parent directory and it seemed to work. I never knew the directory you were running from mattered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already inside myapp, try importing just models.game. Also, be sure to make sure there really is an `__init__.py` in each directory, as you will not be able to import the python module without it.